# Posting a foreign key using ASP.NET MVC and JQuery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know the best practice to post a foreign key.

I have this model.

```
public class Country {
    public int Id {  get;  set;}
    public int Description {  get;  set;}
}
Public class City {
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Description{get; set;}
    public Country Country {get; set;}
}
```

Now in my city View, I'd like to have a dropdown that won't load all countries in the first load, but I'd like to do some sort of autocomplete, Then I saw that method of JQuery of autocomplete, but i don't know how to bind it in my model.

Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: There's a few ways you could do this. You could have a method in the controller that returns the list of items in JSON format and you could call this using JQuery and construct a dropdown to display the results on-screen.
Alternatively, I would have a method in my controller that accepts the chosen `int` ID value from d.down selection. That method returns a partial view which is the second drop-down (autocomplete) list. 
When the user makes a selection, send the chosen ID with Jquery to the controller which will give you the HTML for d.down 2 as HTML and you can place it on-screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## View

All you need to provide in the View is a textbox, like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Country.Id, new { id="CountryId" })
```

Before I go any further, I'm assuming that your `Description` attribute is probably meant to be a `Name` attribute, and in English language, using `Description` to mean `Name` is slightly misleading.

## JQuery

Using JQuery you'll need to do two things, firstly, you'll want to attach the autocomplete to your textbox:

```
$('#CountryId').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetCountries", "MyController")', 
            { term: request.term }, 
            function(data) { 
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Label,
                        value: item.Value
                    }
                }));
            });
    },
    minLength: 2
})
```

The `response` function is an Autocomplete callback that does a few things, [docs for which are here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

This approach works when you have one autocomplete, but if you have more than one autocomplete on your page or only want to write one script to attach autocompletes on every input you need it on, [you can use something similar to this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-amp-jquery-ui-autocomplete.aspx):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { 
    data-autocomplete-url = @Url.Action("GetCountries", "MyController" })
```

Using this JQuery:

```
$('*[data-autocomplete-url]') 
    .each(function () { 
        $(this).autocomplete({ 
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.get($(this).data("autocomplete-url"), ...);
        });
    });
```

## Controller

Finally, the action method in your controller:

```
public JsonResult GetCities(string term) {
    var items = context.Cities
        .Where(x => x.Description.Contains(term))
        .Select(x => new { Label = x.Id, Value = x.Description })
        .Take(10);

    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

where `context` is your repository. In your case I'd assume it was an Entity Framework `DbContext`. The `.Take()` method will dictate how many values are sent back to the client, keeping this number low may help with reactivity of the autocomplete but will not return a large result set for short search terms.

As mentioned above, you should try to make sure that your variables have verbose names.

[One more source here that isn't directly relatable to what you're doing, but may come in handy.](http://techbrij.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: I like the code, thanx alot... It's what I was looking for.